# How to make emacs switch to *scheme* by default when eval / load from the file?

Tags: emacs, scheme, elisp, racket, read-eval-print-loop

The problem:

1. I'm in scheme-mode (simple quack)
2. scheme is already running
3. eval expression
4. it sends the expression to scheme buffer
5. but! doesn't bring that buffer up in 2nd window = no immediate feedback
6. and I have to manually switch second buffer to scheme which is annoying

Some (more recent) modes like `fsharp-mode` or `tuareg` do that automatically. Tried to read quack.el, but didn't find convenient separate function like "pop scheme". It's tangled within `run-scheme` which also changes *focus*. Settings also don't help.

I want to *stay* in my rkt/scm file and see repl buffer pop up if not already popped. Like this simple build logic in sublime-text but with persistent repl.

Maybe I should try `geiser`, but `quack` is ok for now. Just missing few obvious conveniences.

Answer (score 2):

Just run`geiser`. It's in MELPA now, so it's a quick install.

You can also try [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) (which uses geiser) for in-place scheme eval.
<kbd>e</kbd> will eval current expression and display the result in the minibuffer.
<kbd>E</kbd> will eval current expression and insert the result in current buffer.
<kbd>u</kbd> is bound to `undo`, so you can either <kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>Eu</kbd> if you prefer.

Comment: I read somewhere (on geiser page?) that `geiser` more like complements `quack`. And required behaviour looked in `quack` realm.

Comment: Not sure if there are still updates to quack. `geiser` on the other hand is very much alive:
in fact I just had to fix `lispy`'s interaction with `geiser`, since it broke on update.

Comment: Using scheme-mode you can use C-c C-z to switch to *scheme*, and then C-x 2 C-x o C-x b  to split the screen, switch to the other emacs 'window', and then switch back to your code.  Use C-x 3 to split vertically if you'd rather.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing this:

```
(setq scheme-program-name "guile")
(defun run-scheme-2.0 ()
    "Loads your chosen Scheme implementation for interactive development, 
and displays that buffer below your main editing buffer, and makes sure that 
your cursor will be on your code."
    (interactive)
    (if (not (get-buffer "*scheme*"))
      (progn 
        (setq starting-buffer (buffer-name))
        (run-scheme scheme-program-name)
        (split-window-below)
        (other-window 1)
        (shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer)
        (other-window 1)
        (switch-to-buffer starting-buffer))))

(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook 'run-scheme-2.0)
```